# iPhone:How to set AIRPLANE MODE and AUTOLOCK settings in iphone from my app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to set AIRPLANE MODE and  AUTOLOCK settings from my app.

Initially I want to fetch it from iphone settings.

[image]

As shown in the figure what I want to say is if I change AIRPLANE MODE and AUTOLOCK settings from my app it should be changed in the iPhone settings.

For this any code or link which I have to refer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

I understand what jrturton was trying to say - and yes, you can temporarily disable auto lock **while your application is running** but you can't change these system setting from your app.

Comment: Good point, I assumed the question was only concerned with during running since it talks about the timer staying visible, but it does say at the bottom about updating the app settings. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

"Auto Lock" can be controlled by the `idleTimerDisabled` property of `UIApplication`:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

Note that, as Steve points out, this does not change the phone settings, it just prevents the phone going to sleep while your app is running.

You cannot set airplane mode from within your app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm nou sure if it's possible to read this from settings. But you can NOT set this values from your app for security reasons