# iPhone : How to get "Airplane and autolock" information in the app from iPhone setting?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I want to display iPhone's settings `Airplane` feature and `autolock` feature's status in my app.

I got the two links : [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623311/iphonehow-to-set-airplane-mode-and-autolock-settings-in-iphone-from-my-app) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804398/iphone-detect-airplane-mode) but did not get the much details on that.

Can any one tell me how can I get those status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically, you can't. you can disable autolock while your application is running, but you can't change the system setting.. nor can you access it. rather than displaying the airplane mode status, maybe you can show general reachability? i.e. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html or ASIHTTP includes reachability functionality.